# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.20.0 error on django app deployment to AWS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux-2

I deployed the app on Amazon Linux 2 and it seems to be okay except for the part where when I try to access the environment URL it gives the `502 Bad Gateway` error.

Here are my `.ebextensions` which I used:

01_packages.config

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    postgresql-devel: []
    libjpeg-turbo-devel: []

commands:
    setuptools:
      command: pip install setuptools --upgrade
```

db-migrate.config

```
container_commands:
    01_migrate:
        command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py migrate"
        leader_only: true
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: multitennant_v2.settings
```

django.config

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: multitennant_v2/wsgi.py
```

I am not sure how and where to define the nginx commands.

I accessed the nginx error logs and it shows the following:

```
2021/12/29 05:59:11 [error] 691#691: *43880 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.11.220, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.8.112"
2021/12/29 05:59:17 [error] 691#691: *43882 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.39.27, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.8.112"
```

Comment: just to check nginx setting and whether django server was running or not. Was your other django stuff accessible (like apps and views)?? was it connecting o your upstream server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with `djngo.config` file

instead of the above it should be :

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: multitennant_v2.wsgi:application
```

Source: [Deploy a django application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html)